# How to push a Git server repository issues to Github repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

I have a repository on the **Git Server** like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and now I want to switch to [Github](https://github.com/). So I make a copy of my repository on the [Github](https://github.com/) successfully, but the my repository issues (Nearly 200 issue) not copied on the [Github](https://github.com/) repository!

Exist a way to copy all issues on the [Github](https://github.com/) repository without inserting one by one manually !?

Comment: If your Git Server has an API, use it together with [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to avoid any manual work.

Comment: bitbucnket has an API but I don't know how to insert my issues to github! please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708983/how-to-push-a-git-server-repository-issues-to-github-repository#comment49476697_30708983) has said above you can use the BitBucket API to retrieve your current list of issues, or details on a specific issue. Have a look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs for more info on this. In a nutshell, you can make a request to `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<repo-owner-username>/<repo-name>/issues/<ID>` and get back a JSON response of the issue details. You can go to https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org/issues/1 in your browser to see an example of what the response looks like.

Since you wan't to migrate all your issues you can repeatedly make a request to `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org/issues/<ID>`, where ID ranges from 1 to however many issues you have.

Once you have the existing issue details you'll need to write some code to parse the JSON and then use the information provided by BitBucket to make a request to GitHub's API to create the new issue.

You can read up on GitHub's API at https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue. Basically for this you'll make a `POST` request to `https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-owner-username>/<repo-name>/issues` and provide the necessary parameters along with the request. Exactly how you do this will depend on the library you use to make the request. Using CURL the request might look like `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Found an issue","body":"I'm having a problem with this."}' https://api.github.com/repos/behzad-khosravifar/myRepo/issues`.

So putting it all together the [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) might look something like:

```
for (id = 1 to 100)
    issueRawData = http_get('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<owner>/<repo>/issues/'+id)
    issueJson = JSON.parse(issueRawData);
    postData = { "title" : issue.title, "body" : issue.content.raw }
    http_post('https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-owner-username>/<repo-name>/issues/'+id, postData)
}
```

#### Extra & Gotchas

- Iterating over all the issues will mean you're creating issues in GitHub based on issues that have been closed in BitBucket. You can check the 'state' field returned from BitBucket to conditionally create the issue in GitHub. Alternatively create the issue anyway and then use GitHub's API to close the issue after its' been created.
- You'll need to authenticate with GitHub (and possibly BitBucket). https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/ gives details on how to provide auth details when creating the issues in GitHub.